Python set path
I am trying to get my gpu to work with comfyui but I keep getting errors saying
--- Applied providers: ['CPUExecutionProvider'], with options: {'CPUExecutionProvider': {}}
find model: E:\ComfyUI_windows_portable\ComfyUI\models\insightface\models\antelopev2\glintr100.onnx recognition ['None', 3, 112, 112] 127.5 127.5
2024-08-05 08:11:43.6520467 [E:onnxruntime:Default, provider_bridge_ort.cc:1745 onnxruntime::TryGetProviderInfo_CUDA] D:\a\_work\1\s\onnxruntime\core\session\provider_bridge_ort.cc:1426 onnxruntime::ProviderLibrary::Get [ONNXRuntimeError] : 1 : FAIL : LoadLibrary failed with error 126 "" when trying to load "E:\ComfyUI_windows_portable\python_embeded\Lib\site-packages\onnxruntime\capi\onnxruntime_providers_cuda.dll"

I am not sure how to fix this but I read that I should try SET PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\extras\CUPTI\lib64;%PATH%
Sadly I am a total newbie and I have no clue about how to go about doing this. I would very much appreciate your help and other ideas if this is not heading in the right direction.
I have looked all over reading about comfyui, cuda, and python in windows but I just need a mentor.

Forgive me if this is too elementary, but I'm going to assume nothing.

PATH is what's known as an Environment Variable. It's not a Python thing, but an OS thing

PATH is a list of directories which tells the OS where executables are located on your machine

When you are told you need to "add something to your PATH" it means you need to update this variable with some info to let your machine know where an executable is (typically so it can be interacted with via the command line)


All that said, if all you need to do is add something to PATH on your machine, you can run this command from a terminal (i.e. Cmd.exe):
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\extras\CUPTI\lib64;%PATH%

What this does is update the value of the PATH variable to prepend it with C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\extras\CUPTI\lib64
FWIW, this is the general process for adding things to PATH and isn't specific to Python / cuda / etc.
In a more general sense, that looks like this:
SET PATH=[the path you want to add];%PATH%

The ;%PATH% bit is very important, and means...

separate the thing you added from what's already on PATH with a semicolon ;
include the existing value of %PATH% (the percent signs tell the command line to treat the surrounded word as a variable, using its value if it has one, as opposed to just the literal word "PATH")

If you forget this part, you'll end up overwriting PATH with only the thing you meant to add, and this will most likely end up breaking things.

Thank you for being elementary. That was exactly what I was wondering about. I had no clue if "path" was referring to windows, python, cuda, or comfyui.

Glad I could help! If this answer was what you were looking for, please click the check mark to "accept" it so others know this question has been answered.

I did add the path in windows but unfortunately, I am still getting errors when I have the cuda toolkit installed, If I uninstall it and just have the normal nvidia driver installed Comfyui works and generates an image even though I have cuda selected but the cmd shows red errors. It says that the versions don't match, but I do have compatible verisions installed based on what I can find. I guess I am still doing something wrong. I was hoping I could make it work error free without having to reinstall everything.

Error 126 usually indicates a missing or problematic DLL file. To resolve this, you could try a few things.

Verify CUDA installation - Ensure that CUDA is installed correctly and that path C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\extras\CUPTI\lib64 exists. Confirm the CUDA version matches ONNX Runtime's requirements.
Install or update ONNX Runtime - You could run pip install onnxruntime-gpu in a terminal.
Check DLL file issues - Verify that the DLL file onnxruntime_providers_cuda.dll exists in the specified directory (E:\ComfyUI_windows_portable\python_embeded\Lib\site-packages\onnxruntime\capi\).

If nothing else works, try reinstalling comfyUI to ensure all components are properly set up.

Thank you for the suggestion. I will try this and give an update on things.
